Ollama python library not closing socket
In my python code I am doing the following:
ollama_client = ollama.Client(host='http://localhost:11434')
    

and then with this I am calling my embedder function:
def get_embedding(text: str, ollama_client: ollama.Client) -> List[float]:
    """
    Get embedding from Ollama API using direct HTTP request with proper resource management.

    Args:
        text (str): The text to be embedded.

    Returns:
        List[float]: The embedding vector as a list of floats.
    """
    try:
        response = ollama_client.embeddings(model=VECTORIZER_MODELNAME, prompt=text)
        return response['embedding']
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting embedding: {e}")
        # Return zero vector as fallback
        return [0.0] * VECTORIZER_DIMENSION

and in my code I am invoking this for many strings such as the following:
highlight_vector = get_embedding(highlight, ollama_client)

all works well but at the end of my program I get the following warning:
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=15, family=30, type=1, proto=6, laddr=('::1', 50598, 0, 0), raddr=('::1', 11434, 0, 0)>

Python 3.11.7, ollama library 0.3.3
